# How to get previous <LI> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my jQuery application, I have created tabs using list items.

I want to get the previous list item of current list item by using jQuery.

```
if ($("#tabs li.current").length == 0 && $("#tabs li").length > 0) {

    $("#tabs li.current").prev().addClass("current"); // i tried like this...
}
```

But it does not work for me. Please help me.

---

Thank you. I tried this. It also doesn't work for me.

I want to find the previous one when the current one is removed. I think the current list item is removed when executing this line of code.

I tried using the list item id:

```
$("#tabs li").find("#" + tabName+"1").addClass("current");
```

This also does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#tabs li.current").prev().andSelf().toggleClass("current");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in the if statement, namely

`if($("#tabs li.current").length == 0`...

This says "if there are no `<li>` elements with the class `current` within the element with id `tabs`".

As a result, whenever you *do* execute `$("#tabs li.current").prev().addClass("current");`, no element is found, so `.prev()` has nothing for which to find a previous element.

If you want to do this when you remove the current tab, then add a check when a tab is removed to see if it `hasClass('current')`, and, if so, use `.prev().addClass('current')` before you remove it.